# Array updating problem for using map(int,input().split()) in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

for taking list input in the array I used

> map(int,input().split())

but for using this input method I can't modify the array if I Iterated like a[I] then it shows

> TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Can you please tell me how can I resolve this problem?
I am a competitive programmer but I am new to python I  must have take input array by using  map(int,input().split())

Comment: `thing = [int(item) for item in input().split()]`, `thing[I]`

Comment: @wwii. I think it's a challenge so the function is `map(int,input().split())` and can't be a comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list(map(int,input().split()))` instead of `map(int,input().split())` to convert your input to list, because `map` function returns an generator which can not be indexed.

Comment: Thank you so much.. but can you tell me what's wrong in without list?

Comment: `map` function returns an generator. Generator can not be indexed like `x[i]`. Read more about generators in python [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use another function like `list`, use:

```
# Input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
l = [*map(int, input().split())]
print(l)

# Output:
1 2 3 4 5
```